# Loading of providers fails when trying to download new KDE Plasma content

Tags: linux, pop-os, plasma, settings

I am trying to install a new global theme from the system settings. When I click on "Get new global themes..." I get a message that says "Loading of providers from file: https://autoconfig.kde.org/ocs/providers.xml failed". I found a file named providers.xml in my /etc/xdg folder. Other than that, I cannot find anything else related to providers.xml or anything in it. These are the contents of the providers.xml file in my computer:

```
<provider>
<id>api.kde-look.org</id>
<location>https://api.kde-look.org/ocs/v1/</location>
<name>api.kde-look.org</name>
<termsofuse>https://api.kde-look.org/content/terms</termsofuse>
<register>https://api.kde-look.org/register</register>
<services>
<person ocsversion="1.6"/>
<content ocsversion="1.6"/>
</services>
</provider>
</providers>
```

I cannot download any content that includes global themes, cursors, widgets and others. Finally here are my computer's specs:

- PopOS 22.04
- KDE Plasma Version 5.24.7
- Intel Core i7-7700K 8-Core
- 16 GB RAM

Comment: Same issue here on Manjaro ARM (in a VM on a Macbook).